# create a web application that could one-click install, uninstall packages on my ubuntu server

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I just need to create a web application that could one-click packages on my ubuntu server, I really no idea, where to start.. Thought of doing it by php, and due to security issues, it wasn't a fair idea.

Sorry, I'm new to this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Probably not, your web-user (www, apache, etc.) probably does not have (and should not have...) sufficient rights to install packages.

Comment: okay, forget php, you got any other methods to accomplish this?

Comment: The same applies for all web-based methods. The process running the web server should not have write access across your system. If it did, this would be possible but would also have serious security implications.

Comment: this Q would probably be more appropriate on th S.E. http://askubuntu.com site, but the answer would still be the same, don't do it! Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should not do this.**

To answer your question, yes, it is possible. It can be done with doing "sudo apt-get ..." within `shell_exec()`. This would require that the webserver has passwordless access to root powers.

**Did I mention that you should not do this?**

If you are trying to remotely manage a computer, you should use SSH to log in to it and avoid the unnecessary gymnastics of using PHP, or use a web-based interface like [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) that can properly do these things for you.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this.. 
What if I change my question a little bit, I just want to create a web application that could one-click install, uninstall packages on my server remotely. I'm aware of ssh and I'm in need of this kinda application for a reason. My ubuntu server has a root user with a password. 
Not bothering about the php.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track using system()/shell_exec().
I think it "does not work" on your side because your Apache process owner does not have root permission (and you need root to be able to install packages). By the way, its the same for any other programming language implementation you use: you need root to be able to install packages.

You can set your Apache process owner to 'root', but then you'll get this when you try to restart it:

```
Error:    Apache has not been designed to serve pages while
running as root.  There are known race conditions that
will allow any local user to read any file on the system.
If you still desire to serve pages as root then
add -DBIG_SECURITY_HOLE to the CFLAGS env variable
and then rebuild the server.
It is strongly suggested that you instead modify the User
directive in your httpd.conf file to list a non-root
user.
```

You can compile Apache yourself to allow running Apache with root user as indicated above.

To summarize, what you're trying to do is possible BUT you are opening a really big security hole.

YOU SHOULD NOT DO THIS.

Use SSH instead.